# Getting error while creating storage on azure with python script, Getting error message "TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-storage

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.storage.models import StorageAccountCreateParameters
from azure.mgmt.storage.models import (
    StorageAccountCreateParameters,
    StorageAccountUpdateParameters,
    Sku,
    SkuName,
    Kind
)

#getting credentials
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(clientid="",secret="",tenant="")

#storage
storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

#creating storage
storage_async_operation = storage_client.storage_accounts.create("testing345","testcode",StorageAccountCreateParameters(sku=Sku("standard_ragrs"),kind=Kind.storage,location='westus'))
```

I am getting error message like "TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Comment: this looks okay. when does this happen? at what line? can you debug?

Comment: it was working fine, but from last 8 days, I did not check that and now getting error message.

Comment: credentials expired?

Comment: no, credentials  are fine

Comment: debug it, in this case

Comment: unable to get what exact issue, still getting same error

Comment: Add the full traceback text into your question.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely you moved from 1.x SDK series to 2.x or more since this syntax is not allowed anymore:

```
Sku("standard_ragrs")
```

Starting 2.x, every arguments needs to use the keyword only syntax:

```
Sku(name="standard_ragrs")
```

You can find this information on the ChangeLog on PyPI, on version 2.0.0rc1:
https://pypi.org/project/azure-mgmt-storage/

Particularly, this section

> Model signatures now use only keyword-argument syntax. All positional
>   arguments must be re-written as keyword-arguments. To keep
>   auto-completion in most cases, models are now generated for Python 2
>   and Python 3. Python 3 uses the “*” syntax for keyword-only arguments.

To fix your issue, you need then to pin the dependencies of your application, or update your code for the latest releases.

(I work at MS and own this code)

Comment: Thank you so much Laurent. Sku(name="standard_ragrs") it's working for me .